# How to Distill model based Roberta?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'd like apply [distill process](https://towardsdatascience.com/distillation-of-bert-like-models-the-code-73c31e8c2b0a) on a sentiment analysis model ([pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis](https://huggingface.co/pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis)). I'm following all steps, but I don't get good scores of the sentiment in student model (Final model when apply distill process). I don't know where should improve or if I should change library, for example [TextBrewer](https://github.com/airaria/TextBrewer) (It's hardest). You can find source code of distill process [here](https://gist.github.com/remi-or/4814577c59f4f38fcc89729ce4ba21e6).

And I get those scores when I apply distill process

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis')
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis')

# tokenizer.save_pretrained('pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis')
# model.save_pretrained('pysentimiento/robertuito-sentiment-analysis')

nlp = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

text = 'Nosotros somos estudiantes de la Universidad y la amamos demasiado'

print(nlp(text))  # result is good -> [{'label': 'POS', 'score': 0.9251911044120789}] It's positive sentiment

distillator = Distillator(model)  # I start to distill model

# distillator.student.save_pretrained('./pysentimiento/sm/')

new_tokenizer = tokenizer.from_pretrained('./pysentimiento/sm/')

nlp1 = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=distillator.student, tokenizer=new_tokenizer)
nlp2 = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=distillator.teacher, tokenizer=tokenizer)

# [{'label': 'NEU', 'score': 0.335554301738739}] <- student's model has bad score [{'label': 'POS', 'score': 0.9251911044120789}]
print(nlp1(text), nlp2(text))
```

student's config.json has half number of hidden layers

```
"num_attention_heads": 12,
"num_hidden_layers": 6,
```